# How to run operating system command from sas & read number of lines of a file?

Tags: file, command-line, sas, records

```
data student;
infile "E:\student.txt";
input id name $ marks;
run;

data _NULL_;
set student nobs=TotalRecords end=Last;
if Last then 
    do;
        put TotalRecords=;
        /*---------Put your code here--------*/
        /*Code to retrieve number of records */
        /*of file from OS command            */
    end;
run;
```

Hi all, I am working on a program in which I am reading data from text file. After reading the data I want to check number of records(no. of lines) of file are equal to no. of observations of my data set or not, just for validation purpose.

Comment: This is more of a command-line question rather than a SAS question. You can execute OS commands directly using the `x` statement , `system` function, or `call system` routine.

Comment: @MartijnR 
 
FINDSTR /R /N "^.*" "E:\student.txt" | FIND /C ":"   I have tried this command. It prints the no, of lines which are in the file. I tried it on command prompt (Windows) it works fine, but when I use this command in SAS with X, System, call system, systask. It gives error for all of the above. Please tell me how to implement this command in sas & store its result

Comment: @stu-sztukowski   FINDSTR /R /N "^.*" "E:\student.txt" | FIND /C ":" I have tried this command. It prints the no, of lines which are in the file. I tried it on command prompt (Windows) it works fine, but when I use this command in SAS with X, System, call system, systask. It gives error for all of the above. Please tell me how to implement this command in sas & store its result

Comment: You can do this with `%sysexec FINDSTR /R /N "^.*" "E:\student.txt" | FIND /C ":"` or `%sysfunc(system(FINDSTR /R /N "^.*" "E:\student.txt" | FIND /C ":") )`, but you'll need to get `FINDSTR` to return the number of lines that it calculates from reading the .txt file, and not whether the command itself was a success or failure. Otherwise, SAS will only read a 1/0 from the operation.

`%sysexec` automatically populates `&sysrc` with the return code, while `%sysfunc(system() )` will let you read it directly into your own macro variable.

Comment: @stu-sztukowski I tried in your way  but sysrc is returning value zero.

%sysexec FINDSTR /R /N "^.*" "E:\student.txt" | FIND /C ":";
%put No of lines=&sysrc;

Log:----->

%sysexec FINDSTR /R /N "^.*" "E:\student.txt" | FIND /C ":";
%put No of lines=&sysrc;
No of lines=0

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting to validate yourself visually, this information is printed to the log - at least SAS's opinion of how many lines are in the file.

If you're trying to do this automatically, read on.  You don't need OS tools to check this.

Typically, this sort of validation is intending to check a few specific problems:

- Early termination of file reading due to `^Z` character (EOF character)
- Reading two SAS lines from one File line
- Reading one SAS line from two File lines
- File system failure causing SAS to prematurely end file read

All can be fairly easily checked - mostly - by doing a second pass of the file.

```
data linecheck;
  infile yourfile ignoredoseof;
  input;
  lines+1;
run;
```

That will cause SAS to read the number of lines into a variable, which you could then `call symput` or otherwise use to check and see if the original read-in matches it.  All four problems are potentially checked, if the 4th was a temporary failure; of course, if the disk is permanently damaged, no solution (including asking the OS) will help you (since any solution would require reading the file - text files don't have a header or anything that tells you their line length, so you have to read them in).

Comment: FINDSTR /R /N "^.*" "E:\student.txt" | FIND /C ":" I have tried this command. It prints the no, of lines which are in the file. I tried it on command prompt (Windows) it works fine, but when I use this command in SAS with X, System, call system, systask. It gives error for all of the above. Please tell me how to implement this command in sas & store its result

Answer (score 0):

This example uses UNIX WC to gather info on a PARMCARDS file.  While not particularly interesting it serves the example.

```
filename FT15F001 temp;
data wc_info;;
   filevar = catx(' ','/usr/bin/wc',quote(pathname('FT15F001')));
   infile dummy pipe filevar=filevar truncover end=eof;
   do while(not eof);
      input lines words characters filename $256.;
      put _infile_;
      output;
      end;   
   stop;
   parmcards;
how
many


lines
are 
in this parmcards file
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: FINDSTR /R /N "^.*" "E:\student.txt" | FIND /C ":"      I have tried this command. It prints the no, of lines which are in the file. I tried it on command prompt (Windows) it works fine, but when I use this command in SAS with X, System, call system, systask. It gives error for all of the above. Please tell me how to implement this command in sas & store its result

Comment: @data-null  I am reading data from text file. After reading the data I want to check number of records(no. of lines) of file (by executing OS command from SAS) are equal to no. of observations of my data set or not. Refer the code given above.